# How to create a scene through a script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game, I want to make a level editor, and I need to create a new scene on which this level will be located through a script (for a new level). How to do it and is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this in the Unity Docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.CreateScene.html

```
Scene newScene = SceneManager.CreateScene("My New Scene");
```

Be sure to include SceneManagement in the top of your class.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```